# moment end of the day add timezone

Tags: react-native, datetime, momentjs

We have a react native application which using worldwide

I want to show end of the day as utc but cant figure out how to do that.

lets say my time zone is +03:00, so when utc enters the new day my local time should be 03:00, right? How can i show that value?

tried these

```js
moment().utc().endOf('day').format() // -> 2023-02-16T23:59:59Z
moment().utc(true).endOf('day').format() // -> 2023-02-16T23:59:59Z
moment().endOf('day').utc().format() // -> 2023-02-16T20:59:59Z
moment().endOf('day').utc(true).format() // -> 2023-02-16T23:59:59Z
moment.utc().endOf('day').format() // -> 2023-02-16T23:59:59Z
// i need this 2023-02-17T02:59:59Z
```

How can i add that timezone offet to date without using moment-timezone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed like that

```js
const date = moment().utc().endOf('day').toDate()
moment(date).utc(true).format() // -> 2023-02-17T02:59:59Z
```